# Using findAll in BS4 to create list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'll start by saying I'm sort of new with Python. I've been working on a Slack bot recently and here's where I'm at so far.

```
source = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
price = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"pricing"})["quantity"]
```

Here is the HTML code I am trying to scrape.

```
<a class="pricing" saleprice="240.00" quantity="1" added="2017-01-01"> S </a>
<a class="pricing" saleprice="21.00" quantity="5" added="2017-03-14"> M </a>
<a class="pricing" saleprice="139.00" quantity="19" added="2017-06-21"> L </a>
```

When I only use `soup.find()`, I'm able to find the first quantity value but I need all of them within a list. I looked into using a different library like lxml instead of bs4 but didn't have any luck with that either. Any help is really appreciated as I've already spent a long time on this.

Comment: Just to note that `.findAll` is really only for backwards compatibility and I believe is deprecated in leui of more Python-y naming conventions. I'd suggest using `.find_all` moving foward.

Answer (score 3):

The `findAll` method returns a list of bs4 `Tag` elements, so you can't select attributes directly.  However you can select attributes from the items in that iterable with a simple list comprehension.

```
price = [a.get("quantity") for a in soup.findAll("a", {"class":"pricing"})]
```

Note that it's best to use `get` when accessing attributes because it returns `None` (or you can set a default value) if the key does not exist in the `attrs` dictionary.

As pointed out by Jon Clements you could filter by 'class' and 'quantity' if you don't want your list to have `None` items, in case some items have no 'quantity' attribute.

```
price = [a["quantity"] for a in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"pricing", "quantity":True})]
```

Comment: Some might find `soup.select('a.pricing')` more readable... Instead of default values, you can also filter out non-priced elements, eg: `[a['quantity'] for a in soup.find_all("a", class_='pricing', quantity=True)]`

Comment: True, but I prefer the `get` method, it's simpler. You're absolutely right about the `select` and `find_all` though.

Comment: `.get` makes sense if you want a default value and a consistent result length. The filtering makes sense if you don't want empty values. Depending on the use-case - was just pointing out the later option.