# BeautifulSoup - select output

Tags: select, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract several values from a row, I am able to get an output but after a few hours of testing and searching for an answer stuck on something that is probably basic.

For each Row, I would like to get the "Day","Date" and "Total Hours" and then do that for each day of the business week (Mon-Fri)

My output from 'soup.select('#TSRowMonday')' is

```
<tr id="TSRowMonday"><td class="TSDay"><span>Monday</span></td><td align="right" class="TSDay">4/06/2018</td><td align="center"><input class="TSRO" name="TSHour$ctl01" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="08:30"/></td><td align="center"><input class="TSRO" name="TSHour$ctl02" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="01:00"/></td><td align="center"><input class="TSRO" name="TSHour$ctl03" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="17:30"/></td><td align="center" class="TSTB"><input class="TST" id="TSMonTotal" name="TSHour$ctl04" readonly="readonly" tcol="3" trow="0" type="text" value="08:00"/></td></tr>
```

The three peices of information I am trying to extract are:

span>**Monday**

class="TSDay">**4/06/2018**

type="text" value="**08:00**"

then to loop it through the remaining days (#TSRowTuesday, #TSRowWednesday, etc)

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

H

Comment: You can use [find_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410774/using-findall-in-bs4-to-create-list) to create a list of all `tr` tags and loop through them to extract the necessary text from it.

Comment: Hi Siva, Thanks for your response, I've used the find_all to pull the entire table (probably easier than doing row by row, thanks).

Now that I have the table, how do I single out the key peices of data from that table? i.e if I just wanted to extract the 'date', I am assuming I need to pass additional commands in the select/find_all but am stuck there.

Comment: While looping you can use the `find` method to extract the specific values and store them in a list.